# Access MvcResources under System.Web.Mvc from custom helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am working on a custom Html helper extension method with MVC 5.0, and after walking through the source code of the built-in helper method: InputHelper(), I want to use a piece of it in my helper method:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
{
    throw new ArgumentException(MvcResources.Common_NullOrEmpty, "name");
}
```

However, even with the namespace System.Web.Mvc used, I am still getting the error saying: the name 'MvcResources' is not found in the current context.

According to its source code, MvcResources is defined in a .resx file:https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/Properties/MvcResources.resx

And I am sure the source code I shared above is MVC 5.x.

So, can any one help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get resources using `System.Resources.ResourceManager`.

So your Code look like below -

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
{    
    throw new ArgumentException(System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(MyProject.MvcResources)).GetString("name"),"name");//replace `MyProject.MvcResources` by full name (with namspace) of your Resource class
}
```

You can create and user  custom `HtmlHelper` like below.

**Example:**

Helper:

```
public static class HelperClass{
 public static string InputHelper<T>(this HtmlHelper html, object key) {
    return new System.Resources.ResourceManager(typeof(T)).GetString(key.ToString());
 }
}
```

Use:

```
@Html.InputHelper<MyProject.Resouce.MyResouce>("name")
```

Hopefully It's help you.

Comment: thank you for your time. I don't quite follow your idea. In my situation, I am trying to access a resource defined in System.Web.Mvc namespace, which is MvcResources, so I don't have my own resource, I don't understand what you are referring to as '...your Resource class' and 'MyProject.Resouce.MyResouce'. And ArgumentException() accepts two string parameters, a error message and the name of the argument, but in your example, it accepts only one. In one word, I do not have a custom resource class and so there is no point in passing any resource object as generic template parameter.

Comment: "your Resource class" means Every Resources has corresponding C# class. `MyProject.MvcResources` OR `MyProject.Resouce.MyResouce` just my example.You must replace by your own Resouce class  (full name (with namspace)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes the post is old, however this came up in a search today whilst I was looking for the the actual resx file for System.Web.Mvc.Properties.MvcResources (so I could replicate a value in it)

The reason that you cannot access System.Web.Mvc.Properties.MvcResources directly is that it's declared as internal.